# Symfony2 and Command Email sending - send the app_dev email

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I have a Symfony2 command where I am sending some emails.
Everything works fine except the fact that the email is sent as from the dev environement which uses the delivery_address by default.

Here is how it works:

1. Call the command class from the /etc/crontab
2. The class will create the email and send it

   ```
   $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
       ->setContentType("text/html")
       ->setSubject('Daily Digest of Comments, '.$runningConference['name_full'])
       ->setFrom('conferences@mdpi.com')
       ->setTo('email1@test.com')
       ->addBcc('email2@test.com');

   $message->setBody($this->getContainer()->get('templating')->render('ProjectMyBundle:Page:paperCommentsDailyDigestEmailForSubscribers.txt.twig'));

   $this->getApplication()->getKernel()->getContainer()->get('mailer')->send($message);
   ```
3. Each minute, I am senting the email from files with a cronjob.

   ```
   * * * * *      www-data php /var/www/myproject/app/console swiftmailer:spool:send --env=prod
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the problem. For the people in the same situation, you have to call your command with

```
--env=prod
```

because by default the environment is dev.